# Polymer - get an element from parent

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I have an app that will log in with firebase. I'm using polymerfire for this. Got an main app element: `my-app` that has these children:

```
<firebase-app
    auth-domain="my-app-ID.firebaseapp.com"
    database-url="https://my-app-ID.firebaseio.com"
    api-key="my-app-apikey">
</firebase-app>
<firebase-auth
    id="auth"
    user="{{user}}"
    status-known="{{statusKnown}}"
    provider="google"
    on-error="handleError">
</firebase-auth>

<iron-pages selected="{{page}}" attr-for-selected="name">
    <my-loading name="loading"></my-loading>
    <my-home name="home"></my-home>
    <my-dashboard name="dashboard"></my-dashboard>
</iron-pages>
```

`page` changes with the `statusKnown` and `user` property of the `firebase-auth` element. While the `statusKnown` is `false` the `loading` page is visible. When the `statusKnown` is `true` it selects either `home` screen, when the `user` is `null` or the users `dashboard`.

```
  _signInChanged(statusKnown) {
      if(this.statusKnown) {
          if(this.user) {
              this.page = "dashboard"
          } else {
              this.page = "home"
          }
      } else {
          this.page = "loading"
      }
  }
```

the `home` screen has an button to signin and then it's clicked it must call the `firebase-auth` function `signInWithPopup()`. But the `firebase-auth` element cannot be accessed from the `my-home` element. It cannot be found with `document.getElementByID` or passed as an attribute. Or somehow access if with the parent pointer `this.parentElement.$.auth.signInWithPopup()`

How can I get the `auth` element from the child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it different way. Thanks to events and listeners you will be able to propagate some event to parent and then in parent-element just access firebase-auth using `this.$.auth`.

So:

at `my-home` element when you are ready to call firebase auth, just call somethind like: `this.fire("logIn");` and in parent-elemet inside a `ready` function write this:

```
this.addEventListener("logIn", function() {
  this.$.auth.signInWithPopup();
}.bind(this));
```

and that's it.

Comment: Thanks, events are the answer :) and I've already solved it :) but I'm using polymer 2.0. In 2.0 firing events is called with `dispatchEvent` like so: `this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('login', {bubbles: true, composed: true}))` then I can attach and listening function with `<my-home on-login="handleLogin"></my-home>`.

Comment: there is a tag `Polymer 2.x` on stackoverflow and it is great to use it so everyone knows what version you are using. So in future try to use it. anyway i am glad i helped you to bring idea